# Breakable text box in Area 51 profile

Tags: bug, area-51, profile-page

It looks like the Area 51 profile text box can be broken with long text without whitespace. Here is the correct view of my profile on [Electronics.stackexchange.com](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/13400/):

[image]

Note the automatic line breaks. Here is the [Area 51 version](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/66102/):

[image]

Note the text box is now larger than the frame that its in, causing text to be invisible to the user. Problem appears on Google Chrome Version 28.0.1500.71 m and Internet Explorer 10.0.9200.16635/

Comment: I doubt that's broken based on the CSS

Comment: *Doctor, help! It hurts when I do this unusual thing.* Uhh, then stop doing it?

Comment: @CodyGray, uhh so your approach to bug reports is to tell the user "stop causing the bug to happen"?